# Wrap a task to convert its return value

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

The `SendAsync` method of `HttpClient` returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.

What I'm trying to do is to have a `Task<T>` that wraps this task and converts the response to an instance of `T`. For example if I expect the response to contain the JSON representation of `SomeCustomObject`, I would have something like so:

```
public T GetAsT<T> (HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> apiCall = Client.SendAsync(request)
    SomeCustomObject sco = await Wrap (apiCall);
    return sco;
}
```

I can't seem to get this to happen.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If I want to wrap a build task in another build task, the C# tasks are pretty useless to me. I didn't include the C# tag ... I included the C# language to make it more searchable. Whether or not it's appropriate to include 'tags' in the title seems to ignore the context.

Comment: As you are no doubt aware, adding the tag in the tags causes the tag to appear in the `<title>` element, which is what search engines use to search with. Also, these are not "C# Tasks", but rather ".NET Tasks". They have very little to do with the C# Programming language. Proof: If "C# Tasks" are the same thing as "VB.NET Tasks", then that's likely because they are specific neither to C#  nor VB.NET, but rather to .NET.

Comment: No I don't check the source HTML of every site I visit.
Again, C# because I don't care about VB syntax. If an 'Answer' below used VB code, I wouldn't be interested. Yes, they're all .NET, but I want C# specifically.

Comment: That's what the tags are for. Putting the tags in the title is like mixing data with metadata. "Separation of concerns" is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Something along those lines might cut the mustard:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsT<T> (HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    HttpResponseMessage apiCall = await Client.SendAsync(request);
    string data = await apiCall.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
}
```

or if you want to block inside the method and not have the consumer await for it:

```
public T GetAsT<T> (HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    HttpResponseMessage apiCall = Client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    string data = apiCall.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
}
```

Comment: I actually want both of these methods. The which is determined at runtime. I'm intercepting the method calls and if the return value is a `Task<T>` I want to return the task. If the return value is of type `T` then I block until I have both pieces. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Your second method might lead to a deadlock. Blocking with `Task.Result` is usually a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
public static class HttpRequestMessageExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> GetAsT<T>(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
var obj = new HttpRequestMessage(...).GetAsT<SomeCustomObject>();
```